# WPF XAML Loading Images from function

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I have WPF Form where I've created a listview from a childdataview. The listview, amongst other controls, will have an image.

So the datarows from the childdataview have the "Image Name", the location is actually inside a seperate zip file.

I've accomplished the display of the pictures just fine in winforms:

```
If img.newFileFlag = vbTrue Then
            photoDisp.Image = Image.FromFile(img.newFileLocation)
            photoDisp.SizeMode = Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            Dim bp_Name As String = loc
            Dim strm As FileStream = New FileStream(bp_Name, FileMode.Open)
            Dim archive As ZipArchive = New ZipArchive(strm, ZipArchiveMode.Update)
            Dim imageStrm As Stream
            For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries
                If entry.Name.Contains(img.xFileName) Then
                    imageStrm = entry.Open()
                    photoDisp.Image = Image.FromStream(imageStrm)
                    photoDisp.SizeMode = Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            strm.Close()
        End If
```

Write wrong or in between, it works. So i've taken on the task of converting over to WPF and trying to do a bit MVVM as well.

So if i have a listview:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" Background="Red" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConnectedChildView}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="/"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

What's the correct way to get that Image loaded correctly?

In my Viewmodel I can get to the zip file:

```
Public Property BPDProp As BredpackageData
        Get
            Return BPD
        End Get
        Set(value As BredpackageData)
            BPD = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

And in the BredpackageData Class:

```
Public Property BredPackageLocationProperty() As String
        Get
            Return BredPackageLocation
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            BredPackageLocation = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

So i have all the data necessary to use a similar function as my winforms, and I could probably just sneak it into the code behind and make it work, but that feels wrong.

Is there a better, more correct way?

I'd like to post more about what I've tried, but I haven't really tried anything. I can't get anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: You can expose the image as a property on the viewmodel.  It's probably not the best idea to do the extraction at that point (it's generally bad manners to have anything that might be slow to calculate in a property), as long as you're guaranteed to need all of the images and/or there aren't too many of them.  In that case, you would do the extraction when you set up the viewmodel, in the ctor or some kind of initialization function.

Comment: @Craig
There could in theory be 100's of photos within that zip file. I don't think i'd want to expose all of them onload, I wouldn't even know the correct way to do that at the moment.. But it's also possible I'm misunderstanding what you mean. I'm fairly fresh here to WPF and MVVM. I feel as though there must be a straightforward way for the listitem to ask the viewmodel: "I've got this photo name from the itemsource of the listview, can i please have the image stream" and then the viewmodel goes and extracts the photo. I'm currently trying to setup a Command that fires on initialization.

Comment: @Craig I think i'm just going to create a custom class that has the datarow and exposed photo. Have the ListView look at this new observablecollection<new class>. I really thought there'd be a more elegant solution where i could just watch the ChildView and the get the photo with the name later, but I suppose that is above me.

Comment: That's exactly the right idea.  You have an item viewmodel that can be bound to the template for the container, and the main viewmodel exposes a collection of them.  You *could* get the image on-demand when the property gets read, but (as I noted before) that's potentially bad manners if it won't be fast.